# Reading and creating xml like xsd

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-parsing

I am new to working with similar xml. My task: read this xml, including reading attributes (e.g. xdms: type) and tag values ​​(e.g. xdms: organization). And the inverse problem: create exactly the same xml. Tell me technologies in java that I could learn and with which I could solve my problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<xdms:communication xdms:version="2.7" xmlns:xdms="http://www.someLink.com/OAHS"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xdms:header xdms:type="Some type" xdms:uid="SDGDS65G46D54GD"
                 xdms:created="2020-01-02T17:05:20">
        <xdms:source xdms:uid="dfsd4f5sd46fd64sd6f56sd">
            <xdms:organization>My Organization</xdms:organization>
        </xdms:source>
    </xdms:header>
    <xdms:container>
        <xdms:body>Some body</xdms:body>
    </xdms:container>
</xdms:communication>
```

Comment: You mention XSD in your headline and in your tags, but not in the body of your question. What's the relevance of XSD to your problem?

Comment: StackOverflow discourages open-ended questions asking for technology recommendations, so I'm going to vote to close this, not because it's a bad question, but because it's the wrong place to ask it. I would recommend reading Elliotte Rusty Harold's book "Processing XML with Java". Although it's now fairly old, it's still the best there is.

Comment: @MichaelKay Sorry, it seemed to me that the structure is similar to xsd. I repeat, I am new to this.

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks for the recommendation on the book! I will definitely pay attention to her. I apologize for my question, I was just confused. It seems I should pay attention to the createElementNS method. When I find a solution, I will write in my question so that the rest knows.

Comment: Do consider alternative tree models to DOM. DOM is by far the most widely-used tree model for XML in the Java world, but it is the oldest and the worst. Third party libraries like JDOM2 and XOM are much easier to use. And if you like more modern programming idioms like immutable data structures, functional interfaces, streams, and fluent APIs, then take a look at the new "Sapling tree API" in Saxon 10.0 (just out).